# How to display datas from two $.each() function in jquery as two columns in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I'm selecting FeatureName from PlanFeature table and returning it as a JSONRESULT to GETJSON and the code for the following is:

this is the CONTROLLER logic in MVC:

```
public JsonResult FeaturesName()
        {
            var featr = (from feature in db.PlanFeatures select feature.FeatureName).ToList();

            return Json(featr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In Jquery for displaying the feature names:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("FeaturesName")', function (featr) {
                $.each(featr, function (key, value) {

                    $("#features").append("<tr><td><label id='label" + key + "' type='label'>"+value+"</label></td></tr>");
                    $("#featureseditable").append("<tr><td><input id='text"+ key +"' type='text' value="+ value +"/></td></tr>");

                });

            });
```

for displaying the corresponding CHECKBOXES, in controller:

```
public JsonResult checkbox(int planid)
        {
var featuredetails = (from planfeature in db.PlanDetails where planfeature.PlanId_FK==planid select planfeature.Quantity_Type);
 return Json(featuredetails,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In jquery for displaying the checkboxes:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("checkbox")',{planid:$("#planid").val()}, function (featuredetails) {
                $.each(featuredetails, function (k, v) {

                    if (v == "Included")
                    {
                        $("#features").append("<tr><td><input id='Checkbox"+ k +"' type='checkbox' checked='checked' /></td></tr>");
                    }
                    else if (v == "None") 
                    {
                        $("#features").append("<tr><td><input id='Checkbox" + k + "' type='checkbox' unchecked='unchecked' /></td></tr>");
                    }
 });
```

});

Here when I click the Features Button the Features Name and the checkboxes are displayed.
In the PlanFeature table if the Quantity Column contains "Included" then the checkboxes are checked to the corresponding features name.
It was done, but the problem is the FeaturesName are displayed as list firstly and the checkboxes are also listed below FeaturesName

```
eg:)

FeaturesName:
1) Feature 1
2)Feature 2
3) Feature 3

Checkboxes:
1)checkbox 1
2)checkbox 2
3)checkbox 3
```

Now What I need is, I need the FeaturesName and the Checkboxes to be listed like this

```
FeaturesName:   Checkboxes:
1) Feature 1    1)checkbox 1
2)Feature 2     2)checkbox 2 
3) Feature 3    3)checkbox 3
```

Please help me on this issue..
Thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: Change the way you form your HMTL  ? hope you require a UI change

Comment: Are the two lists guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: I did changes in my jquery...but the problem is each() in jquery. There are two each() in jquery..one for getting the featurename from planfeature table and the another each function for getting the checkbox value from Plandetail. so Now I got some trouble with each() function as I'm new to jquery and json.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot There is no problem with the length. The checkbox is taken from plandetail table and the featurename is taken from Planfeature table....Now I use each() in $.getjson() to get the returned json from controller JsonResult as shown in my code...Now I need to do is if (v == "Included") {
                                    $("#features").append("<tr><td><label id='label" + key + "' type='label'>" + value + "</label></td><td><input id='Checkbox" + k + "' type='checkbox' checked='checked' /></td></tr>; but it doesn't work it is going for a long loop..please help me....

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot the two lists are not same....

Comment: If, as it appears, you can build the two lists independently, then you can place them side by side with CSS floats or relative positioning. The javascript/jQuery will remain very simple - only very light modification is required.